# Unknown sql(ite) syntax error

Tags: sqlite

Why is the following invalid, i'm at a loss here?

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mons(id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, keyword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);'
```

From node.js's sqlite3, in coffeescript as:

```
db.parallelize( () ->
    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mons(id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, keyword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);')
    )
```

Exact error:

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
  at Error (native)
```

Comment: sqlite  (padding this comment out now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for an autoincrement primary key in sqlite is

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

and not

```
int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

If you omit the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, you'll get slightly different [autoincrement behavior](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using AUTO_INCREMENT isn't the best idea unless you want unique keys for the lifetime of your db. If you delete a record, that id can never be used again. This constraint will slow your database down and use more memory so if you don't need unique keys, I would suggest dropping this as PRIMARY KEY already has a constraint to resist any identical primary keys.